# pointer to an array int (*ptr)[]

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pointer-to-array

I am trying to understand how a pointer to an array works. A code snippet;

```
#include<stdio.h> 
  
int main() 
{ 
  int arr[3] = { 0 , 8 ,10 };
  int (*ptr)[3] = &arr;
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
  printf("Address (%p) - value( %d)\n", (*ptr+i) , *(*ptr + i));
  return 0; 
}
```

An asterisk `*` derefernces the `ptr` . If `i = 1`, why is `(*ptr+i) = ith value` not `value at ptr + i`.

Comment: It is `value at ptr + i`, it's just that the value at the pointer is the array (basically yet another pointer), so adding `i` to it gets the address of the `i`th value in the array.

Comment: You might like: [C gibberish <-> English](https://cdecl.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The type of `ptr` is `int (*)[3]` (pointer to an array length 3 of `int`). The type of `*ptr` is `int[3]` (array length 3 of `int`). In most expressions, an operand of type `int[3]` is converted to a `int *` (pointer to `int`) pointing to the first element of the array. The expression `(*ptr+i)` results in a pointer to the `i`th element of the array by pointer arithmetic. In the expression `*(*ptr+i)`, the pointer to the `i`th element of the array is dereferenced to produce the value of the `i`th element of the array, which is of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the expressions relate to each other:

```
   ptr  ==  &arr  // int (*)[3] == int (*)[3]
  *ptr  ==   arr  // int [3]    == int [3]
```

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  Thus in the expressions below, `*ptr` and `arr` "decay" from type "3-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", and their values are the address of the first element of `arr`:

```
 (*ptr + i)  ==  (arr + i) == &arr[i]  // int * == int * == int *
*(*ptr + i)  == *(arr + i) ==  arr[i]  // int   == int   == int
```

Answer (score 0):

This one uses `malloc`, but the concept is same as assigning the address of 1-D array.

read the comments inline , for better understanding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NCOLS 5
#define NROWS 2

void function( int (*_2D_ptr_Array)[NCOLS] , int nrows, int ncols );

//enable this to see the demo of accessing elements using pointer to an array 
//disabling this will demo how to pass 2-D array and collect using pointer to an array.

//#define _DEMO_MAIN 

int main()
{
    // a is a pointer to an array of 5 ints
    int (*a)[NCOLS];
    int _2D_Array[NROWS][NCOLS] =   {   
                                        { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
                                        { 60, 70, 80, 90, 100}
                                    };
    int i,j;
    
    #ifdef _DEMO_MAIN
    printf("Enter 10 elements\n");
    
    a = malloc(sizeof(int)*5*2);
    
    printf("a got address at %p\n", a);
    
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            scanf("%d",a[i]+j);

    //printing one dimentional array values
    // *a is equivalent to a[j], when j = 0
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        printf("value  %d is at addr %p\n",*(*a+j),(*a+j));
    
    putchar('\n');
    
    //printing multi-dimentional array values
    // adding j to a[i] or *a gives the next element address in a given row.
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            printf("value %d is at %p\n",*(a[i]+j), a[i]+j);
    
    #else
        //a most common use of pointer to an array is to collect the 2-d array as an argument in function
        function( _2D_Array, NROWS, NCOLS );
    #endif
    
    return 0;
}

void function( int (*_2D_ptr_Array)[NCOLS], int nrows, int ncols ) {
    for(int r = 0; r < nrows ; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < ncols ; c++) 
            printf("%d ", _2D_ptr_Array[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**Note:** The return checks for the functions like `scanf` and `malloc` are not handled purposefully