# Problem searching for a value in a matrix

Tags: c

I wanted to make a function that checks if a value exists in a matrix or not by giving (the matrice + the value I want to check + the line) as parameters and I'm getting an error on the transtype from an integer to a pointer. Please I need a help as soon as possible, thank you:)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool Search(int *Mat[4][4], int val, int numLigne) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
        if (Mat[numLigne][i] == val)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    int Mat[4][4] = {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
        { 9, 10, 11, 12 },
        { 13, 14, 15, 16 }
    };
    int p;
    p = Search(Mat[4][4], 5, 1);
    printf("The number is: %d", p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have declared `Search` such the the first argument is a *pointer to a 4x4 2D matrix*. However, your call `Search(Mat[4][4],5,1)` is passing, as the first argument, an invalid reference to a non-existent element in the matrix `Mat`. There is no element in `Mat` at position 4, 4. `Mat[4][4]` refers to an integer, and your function wants a pointer which is why you see that particular error.

Comment: If an array has 4 elements, then valid indices are 0 to 3. If you use the index 4, you are accessing the array out of bounds.

Comment: `p = Search(Mat,5,1);`

Comment: [pointer to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565939/pointer-to-an-array-int-ptr/65566502#65566502) is what you are looking for collecting 2D-array as function argument

Answer (score 1):

Plenty problems

1. `int *Mat[4][4]` it is the array of pointers to `int`. Not the pointer to array. You want `int Mat[4][4]` here
2. `Search(Mat[4][4],` you do not pass the pointer to the function only the integer value which is taken outside the array bounds. 2 UBs in one call. You want `Search(Mat,` here
3. `for( i=0; i<=4; ++i )` it is wrong as indexes in your array are from 0 to 3, and you integrate to 4. You want `for( i=0; i<4; ++i )`
4. This code

```
    for( i=0; i<=4; ++i )
    {
        if(Mat[numLigne][i] == val  )
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

is equivalent to:

```
        if(Mat[numLigne][0] == val  )
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
```

You will stop on the index `0` as you return on both conditions.

I think you need to read the pointer and array chapters of your favourite C book. You need to read about iterations, `if`s and functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the prototype for `Search` should be `bool Search(int Mat[4][4], int value, int row);` or simply `bool Search(int Mat[][4], int value, int row);`. as posted you declare `Mat` to be a matrix of pointers to `int`.
- the loop `for (i = 0; i <= 4; ++i)` should stop when `i == 4`, hence the test should be `i < 4`.
- if the value if not found in the first column, you immediately return `0` without testing the other columns.
- passing the matrix to the function is written `Search(Mat, 5, 1)`. As posted, you attempt to pass the value of a matrix element outside the matrix.
- `Search` returns a boolean indicating **if** the row contains the value, but the column number is not returned. It would be better to return the column number and return `-1` if the value is not found.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Search(int Mat[4][4], int val, int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        if (Mat[row][i] == val)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;  // not found
}

int main() {
    int Mat[4][4] = {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
        { 9, 10, 11, 12 },
        { 13, 14, 15, 16 }
    };
    int col = Search(Mat, 5, 1);
    if (col >= 0)
        printf("The value %d is at position Mat[%d][%d]\n", 5, 1, col);
    else
        printf("The value %d is not present in row %d of Mat\n", 5, 1);

    return 0;
}
```