# Why this code exit before i entering mark of students?

Tags: c

I have run a c code to receive name and mark of students .but after entering name of student, program exit immediately.is there anything wrong?
I have attached code also.

```css
/******************************************************************************

                            Online C Compiler.
                Code, Compile, Run and Debug C program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/
#define STUDENT 5
#define SUBJECT 4
#include <stdio.h>
char name[STUDENT][20];
int mark[STUDENT][SUBJECT+1];

void get_list(char *string[],int array[] [SUBJECT+1], int m, int n)
{
int i, j, (*rowptr) [SUBJECT+1] = array;
for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
scanf("%s", string[i]);
for(j = 0; j < SUBJECT; j++)
scanf("%d", &(*(rowptr + i)) [j]);
}
}
int main()
{
    printf("Enter the name and mark of the student\n");
    get_list(name,mark,STUDENT,SUBJECT);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565939/pointer-to-an-array-int-ptr/65566502#65566502) will help understand how to read values into 2-D arrays

Answer (score 0):

An array when passed to a function will decay to a pointer. In case of 2-D arrays, just the first dimension / index will will decay. Using this should work:

```
void get_list(char (*string)[20],int array[] [SUBJECT+1], int m, int n)
```

Here `string` is a pointer to an array of `20` chars.

Also, you may want to separate the message asking for the name and the marks. That way it will be easier to understand what you have to enter. Consider moving the `print` statements inside the loops.

Comment: @Wounder Please consider accepting / upvoting the answer if it helped.